# Performance Issue in Oracle (Difference between common table expressions and global temp table)

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I am having a performance issue for the one of my queries.

The structure of the query is like below

```
With a02 as  
    (...
    );     

SELECT *
FROM
a02
inner join   
a03 on a02.id=a03.id;
```

Table a02 is around 10000 rows and table a03 is around 40000 rows. The query takes about **1.5 hours** to run.

However, if I create a02 as a global temp table and then run the query below, it takes less then **5 mins**. Is that a normal behavior?

```
SELECT *
FROM
a02
inner join   
a03 on a02.id=a03.id
```

I am hesitated to use global temp table as we sometimes get the following message when drop the table:

DROP TABLE A02;

SQL Error: ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use
14452. 00000 -  "attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use"

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have updated the sql for a simplified case. The main issue I don't understand is why the performance has so much difference between common table expression and global temp table.

Comment: hey. could you provide plans for these queries? It'll be a quite easier to explaint the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

When you create a global temporary table (or even a local temporary table), Oracle has good statistics on the table -- because you just created it.  This can affect the execution plan.

It would seem that Oracle is choosing a suboptimal execution plan for the query.  I would suggest creating an index on `id` in each of the tables -- if possible.  Or at least have an index on `a03(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend identifying the SQL id for the query then using the SQL Monitor Report as it will tell you exactly what the execution plan is and where the SQL is spending most of it's time.

A simple way to get the SQL Monitor Report from SQL*Plus follows:

```
spool c:\temp\SQL_Monitor_rpt.html

SET LONG 1000000
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1000000
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIM ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

alter session set "_with_subquery" = optimizer;

SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.report_sql_monitor(
  sql_id       => '&SQLID' ,
  type         => 'HTML',
  report_level => 'ALL') AS report
FROM dual;

spool off
```

Most likely there is a full table scan going on plus joins without the use of an index. You should probably index the columns in both tables that are involved in the join condition.  Also, you can try the use of the /*+ MATERIALIZE */ hint in your WITH clause sub queries to mimic a Global Temporary Table without actually needing one.